# Crystal Reports Class Not Registered ReportDocument

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2008, 32bit-64bit, crystal-reports-2010

I have a very similar problem as in this post: [Crystal Reports "Class not registered" WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825183/crystal-reports-class-not-registered-wpf)

I am installing Crystal Reports version 13.0 on a Windows 2008 R2 64bit server and I am getting this error when I try to create a ReportDocument like so when running it on the server:

```
Dim rptDoc As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
```

Error Message

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{F734A321-8381-4FFD-A614-139E8906DC83} failed due to the following error: 
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

What I tried that hasn't worked for me:

- Made sure my project is x86
- Installed the Crystal Reports runtime engine for 32 and 64 bit (CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_6.msi and CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_6.msi) on the server
  http://www.sap.com/campaign/ne/free_trial/crystal_reports_visual_studio/wty_int_crvs.epx?Level=1&FormResultID=ef699e2c-
- Checked the registry entry on the server for {F734A321-8381-4FFD-A614-139E8906DC83} and it points to C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\clientdoc.dll

It runs from my Windows 7 32bit machine without a problem.

Any other things I can try?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that it was another missing .dll that doesn't install with the CRVS2010 runtime engine.

Comment: what is the name of that dll and how can i get one ? I am having similar issue.

Comment: Me too, please provide us with the name.

Comment: I should have posted the .dll name. I am no longer working on the project. I will check my notes and post the .dll if I can find it.

Comment: "And the murderer is.. Look at the time, gotta go!"